Error "extra alignement tab" when adding bidi package with nicematrix
It seems that bidi package do  not support nicematrix, this simple example give error
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Not working example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\frac12 & -\frac12 \\
\frac13 & \frac14 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}

What cause this extra alignement tab error?, and is there a quick fix for the issue?

It seems the nicematrix and bidi are not compatible. Can you try replacing nicematrix with other matrix packages such as bmatrix?

Is there a question?

@UdiFogiel  what cause this extra alignement tab error? (the direction of text is LTR), and is there a  quick fix for the issue.

@NaveedAhmed the problem is that all environments defined from  nicematrix package give this issue.

Yes that is why I said these are not compatible with each other and you might need to replace nicematrix with another package.

bidi patches the array package in a faulty way.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{bidi}

\makeatletter
\def\@tabular{%
  \leavevmode
  \UseTaggingSocket{tbl/hmode/begin}% <---------------------
  \hbox \bgroup\if@RTLtab\beginR \fi $\col@sep\tabcolsep \let\d@llarbegin\begingroup
                                    \let\d@llarend\endgroup
  \@tabarray}
  
\def\endtabular{\endarray $\if@RTLtab\endR\fi\egroup
  \UseTaggingSocket{tbl/hmode/end}% <---------------------
}
\expandafter\let\csname endtabular*\endcsname=\endtabular

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\@array[#1]#2{
  \@tempdima \ht \strutbox
  \advance \@tempdima by\extrarowheight
  \setbox \@arstrutbox \hbox{\vrule
             \@height \arraystretch \@tempdima
             \@depth \arraystretch \dp \strutbox
             \@width \z@}
  \tbl_save_outer_table_cols: % <---------------------
  \begingroup
  \@mkpream{#2}
  \tbl_count_table_cols: % <---------------------
  \xdef\@preamble{\noexpand \ar@ialign \@halignto % <---------------------
                  \bgroup \@arstrut 
                  \UseTaggingSocket{tbl/row/begin} % <---------------------
                  \tbl_init_cell_data_for_row: % <---------------------
                  \@preamble
                          \tabskip \z@ \cr}
  \endgroup
  \@arrayleft
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi \fi
  \bgroup
  \let \@sharp ##\let \protect \relax
  \lineskip \z@
  \baselineskip \z@
  \mathsurround \z@ % <---------------------
  \let\\\@arraycr \let\tabularnewline\\\let\par\@empty 
  \UseTaggingSocket{tbl/init} % <---------------------
  \if@RTLtab\hbox\bgroup\beginR\@hboxRconstructtrue\if #1t\vtop \else \vbox  \fi\bgroup\fi
  \@preamble}
  \let\@@array\@array % <---------------------
\def\@tabarray{\@ifnextchar[{\@@array}{\@@array[c]}} % <--------------------- this one should be removed from bidi

\def\endarray{\tbl_crcr:n{endarray} % <---------------------
\egroup\if@RTLtab\egroup\endR\egroup\fi 
\UseTaggingSocket{tbl/finalize} % <---------------------
\tbl_restore_outer_cell_data: % <---------------------
\egroup \@arrayright \gdef\@preamble{}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}
\frac12 & -\frac12 \\
\frac13 & \frac14 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}

I've marked the lines that should be changed in array-xetex-bidi.def. Some of the lines are need to be changed because of an update in array, some for new tgging features, but the line
\def\@tabarray{\@ifnextchar[{\@array}{\@array[c]}}

looks like a very old bug. Going all the way back to 2008, it looks like it should be
\let\@@array\@array

Note that I'm not sure how LaTeX's tagging is works, and especially how it interacts with TeX--XeT.
